# Structure of 'Be you never so high...'

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> In an English High Court case in 1977, the late Lord Denning summed up the gist of the
>   principle of the rule of law when he said:
>
> > To every subject in this land, no matter how powerful, I would use Thomas Fuller’s
> >     words over 300 years ago: ‘**Be you never so high**, the law is above you.’

Source: P7, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

I know that [Thomas Fuller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Fuller) lived in the 1600s, but still want to learn about the grammar and structure.

1. What form is **be** in; it looks the English present subjunctive?
2. How to anatomize/parse/unravel **Be you never**?
   I can guess the meaning here as "Even if you were so high..."

Comment: It's 16th-century English. I think in modern English, it could be phrased as either "You are never so high (because/since/as/for/;) the law is above you," or "Never be so high (because/since/as/for/;) the law is above you," depending on context.

Comment: How knowledgeable you are! :-) @DamkerngT.

Comment: The best modern English interpretation is "No matter how high you are, the law is above you".

Answer (score 3):

You have guessed very well, and arrived at the meaning.

- *Be* here is indeed the old subjunctive, now used only in *mandatives* (“...ordered that he ***be*** released...”). Its former use as a conditional is no longer productive; it lingers today only in some traditional and fossilized expressions (“...***be*** he alive or ***be*** he dead”).
- *Never* here, as oerkelens observes, is a negative form of *ever* in its oldest sense of “at every time, in every degree”—the same *ever* found in *whatever, however, whoever*, &c. This is another fossilized use: *never* has been substituted for *ever* in conditional clauses bearing a sense of negation since the waning days of Old English. Today we would express this negative sense with an *-ever* compound or, as you suggest, with *even*:

  > How**ever** high you are, the law is still above you.
  >   **Even** if you are ever so high, the law is still above you.

Answer (score 1):

Be ye never is synonymous, exactly, with though ye be never

The word "be" is just a contraction of albe, which is a contraction of ALBEIT which mean "though it may be" and is still used, albeit rarely. So at full length it is

albeit ye be never

( See eg Spenser Shepheard's calendar) "Albe forswonk and forswot I am"

The same form is used in the old rhyme

Fee-fi-fo-fum,
I smell the blood of an Englishman,
Be he alive, or be he dead
I'll grind his bones to make my bread.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's have a look at *never*. In many expressions, *never* and *ever* have similar, almost identical meanings:

> The water was higher than (n)ever before.
>   I was as happy as I had (n)ever been.

Then, the use of the *imperative* here is reminiscent of modern expression like:

> Try as you may, you won't catch me.
>   Study all you want, you will fail the exam.

These two loosely combined would lead me to formulate the sentence in question more or less as follows:

> Be as high as [you can] (n)ever [be], [but] the law is [still] above you.

Comment: Did you come up with your first two sentences yourself, or are they quotes from something? To me, _ever_ and _never_ cannot be swapped in and out without changing the rest of the sentence. "I was happier than I had never been before" (meaning I have never been this happy) vs. "I was as happy as I had ever been" (meaning My level of happiness is equal to my happiness at some prior point in my life).