# How can "never" and "ever" be identical in meaning?

Tags: word-usage

I came across two sentences which were:

The water was higher than (n)ever before.

I was as happy as I had (n)ever been.

I am confused as to how can "ever" be substituted by "never" in these sentences?  I haven't seen "never" being used in that way. 
 [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31619/structure-of-be-you-never-so-high&ved=2ahUKEwj6oITSm-HhAhUaSY8KHcdiCPcQFjACegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw04LI_ZmVV3crqXR9w5t2Zi) is the link to the sentences.

Comment: Did the passages actually read ***n**ever*? If so, they were ungrammatical.

Comment: As StoneyB says, **never** doesn't fit in either sentence. Are you sure that the sentences were not intended for students to make the correct choice?

Comment: I find these sentences in a post on this very site. Link to that post - https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31619/structure-of-be-you-never-so-high&ved=2ahUKEwj6oITSm-HhAhUaSY8KHcdiCPcQFjACegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw04LI_ZmVV3crqXR9w5t2Zi

Comment: That question does not have an accepted answer. It's possible those are bad examples.

Comment: @Stoneyb- you yourself acknowledged in that post that use of "never" as a substitute for "ever" is possible.

Comment: @Kelvin The answer specifically says that is *fossilized* and *waning* usage. It goes on to say that "today we would express this negative sense with an *-ever* compound or, as you suggest, with *even*."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use 'never' in the context of the quotations you cite in modern English, in fact I don't believe those sentences could use 'never' in an archaic sense either. If you used 'never' in those sentences, I can assure you native English speakers would think you were making a mistake.

You can, of course, reword the sentences to use never.

> The water had never been so high.
>
> I had never been so happy.

But, you're really saying something quite different, where the negative sense of never makes sense.